# Proving or disproving the continuity of a function

Tags: limits, continuity

I have a prove/disprove question about continuous functions.
I am not sure if the following how to prove or disprove the following claim.
Let $x_0 \in \Bbb R$ and let $f,g$ be two functions that are defined on a neighborhood of $x_0$.
If $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, $g$ is not continuous at $x_0$, and $f(x_0)=0$ then $h=f \cdot g$ is continuous at $x_0$.
This claim seems simple but I am not able to find a counterexample nor proof.
Any assistance will be welcomed.

Comment: Hint: What happens if $g$ is unbounded in any neighborhood of $x_0$?

Comment: then $\lim_{x\to x_0} g(x)= \infty $  It is a good example that $g$ is not continuous at $x_0$ but I am not sure how it helps me disproving that $h$ is continuous at $x_0$

Comment: That (finite) limit doesn't exist for any non-removable discontinuity as well. However, I was aiming for what might happen to $f\cdot g$ if $g$ is unbounded. Or vice versa: Can we prove the desired statement in the bounded case?

Comment: Well, if it's bounded then yes.

Comment: Then try to assemble a full proof. Then think about what goes wrong in the unbounded case. What is a typical unbounded function, say at $x_0=0$?

Comment: a good unbounded function for $x_0=0$ will be $g(x)={1 \over x}$ but it contradicts the fact that $g$ is defined in a neighborhood of $x_0$

Comment: @PaulSinclair The question was treating the product function, not the composition.

Comment: @CuriousScientist The choice $g(x)=\frac 1x$ is very good, just choose $g(0)=0$ (or any other number). Then your function is well-defined, but not continuous at $x=0$. Now, can you complete the counterexample?

Comment: @CuriousScientist - so it is. My apologies for misreading it.

Comment: @Benjamin Yes I found a counterexample. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

To conclude this question, I summarize the hints given in the remarks above.

The following statement gives sufficient conditions for the continuity of $f\cdot g$.
**Lemma.** *Let $x_0\in \mathbb R$, let $\varepsilon>0$ and let $f,g:(x_0-\varepsilon,x_0+\varepsilon)\to\mathbb R$. If $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, $f(x_0)=0$ and $g$ is bounded, then $f\cdot g$ is continuous at $x_0$.*
*Remark.* The proof easily follows from the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-definition of continuity.

If $g$ is unbounded, then a counterexample is easily constructed.
 **Counterexample.** $x_0=0$, $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=\begin{cases}\frac 1x & \mbox{for}\ x\ne 0,\\ 0 & \mbox{for}\ x=0.\end{cases}\quad $
Then $$ f\cdot g (x) = \begin{cases}1 & \mbox{for}\ x\ne 0, \\ 0 & \mbox{for}\ x=0 \end{cases}  $$
is not continuous at $x_0$.